# How to convert qml to python3 with pyuic5?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am using QtCreator3 on Qt5. I have designed a UI using qml. Now I want to convert it to python3 using pyuic5. How should I do?

mygui.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }

        Image {
            id: image1
            x: 130
            y: 130
            width: 100
            height: 100
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "microphono_logo.jpg"
        }

        Text {
            id: text1
            x: 133
            y: 281
            text: qsTr("Click & Speak")
            font.family: "Times New Roman"
            font.pixelSize: 16
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with QML, but I don't think `uic`/`pyuic` take QML as input. They take `.ui` files, which are XML files generated by Qt designer.

Comment: Yah, I have got it. But do you know how can I convert qml to xml to ui?

Comment: You are not supposed to convert qml to python, like with pyuic. QML is meant to be loaded directly by python code. See this example - http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/qml.html#ref-integrating-qml

Comment: That example doesn't actually tell you how to use Qml with PyQt5. The problem is that the components changed from Qt4 to Qt5. Here is an example that works with Qt4 - http://wiki.qt.io/PySide-and-QML-Playground

Answer (score -1):

**At the first**, you must save your file designed as .qml file in **QT Design Studio**, then open .qml file with **QT creator** and save as .ui

**At the end**, you can convert ui file to py file with the below syntax

pyuic5 -o mygui.py mygui.ui